# Data not displayed correctly when read from TCP socket Java

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, dlt-daemon

I'm new to java sockets and processes. I'm trying to read information from a TCP socket, but when I received the data, some information was not displayed correctly. (I think it might be an encoding problem, the process I'm reading from is a Genivi DLT daemon).

Here is a sample of my code:

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {

            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);

            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(reader);         

            String line;


            while((line = br1.readLine())!=null) {
                String s = br1.readLine();
                byte[] utf8Bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
                if(s.contains("SYS"))
                    System.out.println(s);
            }
```

Here is a photo of how [the data that should be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE5FT.png).

And here it's how it is actually displayed to the console:

```
ÒWAVAè5ÓrQSYS ² (PathologyCollectorCPU.cpp: getLoad(...)@69): {"Name": "Core", "cpuName": "cpu0", "percent": 33, "totalUser": 1533306, "totalNice:" 0, "totalSys": 1216838, "totalIdle": 5681926}
```

Does anybody has an idea why this might be, or some approaches I should take in solving my problem?

Edit: 
After some digging I think I have found some information about the protocol, here: https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/foundation/1-0/AUTOSAR_PRS_DiagnosticLogAndTraceProtocol.pdf at page 16. If you have anymore further advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you get the raw data. Try to take the first four bytes and to convert it in an integer

Comment: You're reading the data as lines of text, but it doesn't look like it's sending lines of text. You need to find out the protocol that it uses and parse it properly.

Comment: You are throwing away every odd line. Get rid of the inner call to `readLine()`. And if the data isn't lines, don't use `readLine()`, and if it isn't text, don't use a `Reader`.

Comment: Can your recommend some other ways to read the input stream please? Should I use a scanner?

Comment: Not unless it's text. You will have to break down and tell us what is actualy in the input stream.

Comment: The protocol document you have now provided shows that these messages are neither lines nor text. You will therefore need to throw this all away and start again with a `DataInputStream`.

Comment: The new link for Autosar_prs_diagnosticlogandtraceprotocol.pdf here: https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/foundation/1-0/AUTOSAR_PRS_DiagnosticLogAndTraceProtocol.pdf

Answer (score -1):

You are using TCP (Transmission Control Protocol) and it sends data over the network by a stream. So you need to define the "data-length" for each package you sent.

When the client/service receives that data stream, it bases on the "data-length" value to read exactly the number of bytes for a package.

You can check out the example below for more detail:

```
private void __updateRecvHeaderData(byte[] bytes) {
    if (bytes.length >= Constants.HEADER_BYTES) { // header length
        byte[] header = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 0, Constants.HEADER_BYTES);
        __dataSize = MessagePacker.byteToShort(header); // network to host short
        __recvHeader = false;
        // package = |2 bytes header| <content bytes> |
        byte[] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, Constants.HEADER_BYTES, __dataSize + Constants.HEADER_BYTES);
        __onRecvData(data); // recursion
    }
}
```

The file class can be found here: [TCP receive and split the stream data by data-length](https://github.com/congcoi123/tenio-libgdx/blob/master/tenio-libgdx/src/main/java/com/tenio/gdx/net/TCP.java)

Comment: The OP is using an existing protoco of undisclosed nature. It may or may not have length words.

Comment: "undisclosed nature" so even you do not know about that, you marked my answers as a "not useful" answer.

Comment: You don't know who marked your answer, and the fact that the protocol is undisclosed doesn't mean that you are free to redefine it arbitrarily.

Comment: After some digging I think I have found some information about the protocol, here: https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/foundation/1-0/AUTOSAR_PRS_DiagnosticLogAndTraceProtocol.pdf at page 16. If you have anymore further advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @LiviuIosim That information should be in your question, certainly not here under this answer which is bound to be deleted.

Comment: @user207421 I edited my question with the information, thank you for your advice.